# ODataActionParameters to have a property with default value

Tags: c#, odata, webapi

I have a scenario were I need to add an optional parameter to the existing oData controller action. So that existing calls wont break and new calls can add this optionally. I have tried the following

1. Reading the value from ODataActionParameters as nullable `var optionalParam = parameters["optionalParam"] as Boolean?;`
2. Adding it as additional param (tried nullable) and giving a default value `GetSearchdata([FromBody]ODataActionParameters parameters, bool optionalParam = false)`
3. using additional param and tagging it as from Uri `GetSearchdata([FromBody]ODataActionParameters parameters, [FromUri] bool? optionalParam = false)`

but all these are giving me error if the parameter is not passed in the body. What is the right way to do this?

> error":{
> "code":"","message":"The request is invalid.","innererror":{
> "message":"parameters : One or more parameters of the operation 'GetSearchdata' are missing from the request payload. The
> missing parameters are: optionalParam.\r\n","type":"","stacktrace":""
> }   }

Existing function as follows

```
[HttpPost]
[EnableQuery(MaxExpansionDepth = 100)]
public AdvancedSearchdata GetSearchdata([FromBody]ODataActionParameters parameters)
{
    var moduleIdsObject = parameters["moduleIds"] as IEnumerable<int>;
    return (service.GetSearchdata(moduleIdsObject.ToList(), false));
}
```

Comment: What is the url of  existing  calls?

Comment: Host\controller\GetSearchData. Body contains the json

Comment: Why you don't add  optional param to ODataActionParameters  by creating a new type that inherits

Comment: tried and getting this error now.
"error":{
    "code":"","message":"The request entity's media type 'application/json' is not supported for this resource.","innererror":{
      "message":"No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'ODataActionParametersOptional' from content with media type 'application/json'."}

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a parameter with question mark in the route.

Please refer the belo example from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#optional).

```
public class BooksController : ApiController
{
    [Route("api/books/locale/{lcid:int?}")]
    public IEnumerable<Book> GetBooksByLocale(int lcid = 1033) { ... }
}
```

In this example, /api/books/locale/1033 and /api/books/locale return the same resource.

Comment: not working with oDataController